# Splitting a string every n lines using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
"LINE 1.
LINE 2.
LINE 3.
LINE 4.
LINE 5.
LINE 6."
```

Suppose i want to split the above string every 3 lines using the `split()` method, what regex delimiter should i use to produce something like this :

```
["LINE 1.
LINE 2.
LINE 3.",
"LINE 4.
LINE 5.
LINE 6."]
```

Comment: using which example???///

Comment: What about the line 7?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: The example string is invalid, unless it is not directly read from a text file.

Comment: Ooops! I thought its a Python question. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6aaefn2/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't want to use `split()` here because you would need a regex engine with full [lookaround assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) support for that. Fortunately, `.match()` can do this just as well (arguably even better):

```
result = subject.match(/(?:^.*$\n?){1,3}/mg);
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/hX2zJ7/2).

**Explanation:**

```
(?:    # Start a non-capturing group that matches...
 ^     # (from the start of a line)
 .*    # any number of non-newline characters
 $     # (until the end of the line).
 \n?   # Then it matches a newline character, if present.
){1,3} # It repeats this three times. If there are less than three lines
       # at the end of the string, it is content with matching two or one, as well.
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I was sure i could use `split()` with regex but i never knew `match()` could work as well in junction with flags.

Answer (score 0):

What a nice, clean answer, Tim. I needed a Python version, and this seems to cut it:

```
lines = """LINE 1.
LINE 2.
LINE 3.
LINE 4.
LINE 5.
LINE 6."""

import re
print(re.compile("(?:^.*$\n?){1,3}",re.M).findall(lines))
```

Gives the result

```
['LINE 1.\nLINE 2.\nLINE 3.\n', 'LINE 4.\nLINE 5.\nLINE 6.']
```

Subsituting with 4 instead of 3 should give

```
['LINE 1.\nLINE 2.\nLINE 3.\nLINE 4.\n', 'LINE 5.\nLINE 6.']
```

And indeed it does!

Comment: I do not see how this contributes to answering the question. "Thanks." and "It works." are not even appreciated comments, even less answers. Please add some details to make the helpful additions more obvious. Otherwise this gives quite a strong impression of not actually being an answer.

Comment: I have no saying in what kinds of strong impressions my answer gives You. Your comment on the other hand suggests I should care. I don't. Thanks for the edit, Zoe.